# Are there any boat tours for Lake Baikal?

Tags: tours, russia, siberia, baikal

I am interested in visiting [Lake Baikal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_baikal) and exploring the areas around the lake.  What is the best way of doing so and which nearby town should I use as my homebase?  I'd expect using a boat to go from the west to the east side is much easier than traveling by land.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to visit Lake Khövsgöl?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6566/what-is-the-best-way-to-visit-lake-khovsgol)

Comment: @Karlson - it's a different lake, no?

Comment: @MarkMayo The question I linked asks about both.

Comment: @Karlson that's because you edited it.  I'd rather keep them separate in case I only want to visit one and not the other due to travel restrictions or accommodations or something.

Comment: @yx. You can view what was edited and notice it was only the title. The body is same as you have created.

Comment: @Karlson yes but they are still two different lakes in two different countries

Comment: @yx.  When editing the questions read what you're writing because you changed the title leaving the question referring to both.

Comment: @Karlson that was intentional, because I wanted people to add any insights if they had visited both at the same time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As russian, I should mention other firm, much more popular here in Russian:

[Baikal Dreams](http://www.baikal-dream.ru/en/eko-baikal-proekt/volunteering.html)

They have a good set of offers, including Eco projects with volunteer work (linked above), and more traditional tours.

I think you should check the [Active tours to Baikal](http://www.baikal-dream.ru/en/tour-na-baikal/sports.html) - if they are offering the climbing tour, they definitely can provide a tour with boat :) Even if they don't, you can order the guided tour, and take the boat with you.

Another interesting site is about [the ships across the Baikal](http://www.magicbaikal.ru/rest/time-table.htm), with schedule of department (only in Russian).

Good luck with your tours and welcome to Russia.

PS: All of my friends who have visited the Baikal were using their own initiative - order tickets to the Irkutsk, and after that move to the Baikal and camp there in open zones - outdoor tourism is allowed in Russia and very popular from the Soviet times.

If you have a friends inside Russia, try to use this option - its much more cheaper and fun :)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about the Lake Khövsgöl but Baikal is pretty easy to get to.

There is a [lot of tours being operated in the area](http://www.gobaikal.com/tourism/) and there is a major city which you can [fly, drive, train ride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irkutsk) into to get started.  And little did I know about [this hotel](http://www.select-a-room.com/hotel/russia/irkutsk/baikal--lystvyanka--hotel) which looks to be right on the lake.

Answer (score 4):

Choose Irkutsk as home base. Travel to Olkhon island and rent a boat from there (cheaper) and/or join some group for a day boat trip. Using a boat to go from the west to the east coast is more exciting and quicker, but not cheaper. [Public hydrofoil](http://www.baikalex.com/cruise/) goes on every Monday in July and August. Departure Olkhon (Khuzir village) at 5pm; arrives Ust-Barguzin three and a half hours later.