# What is the best way to visit both Lake Khövsgöl and Lake Baikal?

Tags: planning, russia, mongolia, siberia, baikal

I am interested in a trip to visit both [Lake Khövsgöl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Kh%C3%B6vsg%C3%B6l) and [Lake Baikal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6564/are-there-any-boat-tours-for-lake-baikal).  Khövsgöl seems to be in an extremely remote area so I'm not sure what is the best way to visit the lake.  What is the best way to get there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, can't provide any english-language links.
Try to contact [this firm](http://www.hubsugul.ru/article.php?id=39&c=2), they have amazing pack of offers, such as tour to the Lake Khövsgöl on horse or even hunting!

[image]

[image]
You'll stay in lovely houses like this, they have sattelite TV there and traditional Mongolian furniture:

[image]

[image]

[image]